# Is it possible to reset a progress bar with code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, progress-bar

He guys
im programing a 2d race game with c#.
and im stuck on this piece for ever.
i was wondering if its possible to reset a progress bar with code.

```
        if (BugRed.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Pitstop.Bounds))
        {
            Fuel2.??
        }
```

BugRed and Pitstop are pictureboxes.
When BugRed inter sects with the pitstop.
i want the value of the progress bar to be 100 again.
Fuel2 is the name of my progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the **Value** property. In C# many simple controls use Value for the data object it typically holds.

```
if (BugRed.Bounds.IntersectsWith(Pitstop.Bounds))
{
    Fuel2.Value = 100;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I agree with that. I will change "most" to say "many simple"

Comment: @Owen: "Some" would be more factual. :)